# Jquery mobile and wrapper

Tags: ios, ios5, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've developed a phoneGap app for iOS and it works.
Now I'm trying to switch it on JqueryMobile in order to improve graphic.
This is the code of index.html page.
What must I change to make it works with JQueryMobile?

I tried to use css styles and library of jQueryMobile and modify header and footer but I can't understand where I must place `<div data-role="page">` in my file.
I haven't also understood if I must leave `id=header` and `class=header` or not.

```
<head>
    <title>x Directory</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="ChildBrowser.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-WebInspector.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="header" class="header">
    <a href="index.html" class="nav" id="nav" style="display:none;">Home</a>
    <img src="img/mob.png" class="logo" id="logo"/>
    <h1>xAsk</h1>       
</div>

<div id="wrapper">

    <ul id="xList" class="icon-list"></ul>

</div>

<div id="wrapper_hidden">
    <div>
        <div id="employeeDetails">
            <img id="xPic"/>
            <h3 id="xName"></h3>
            <p id="xEmail"></p>
            <p id="city"></p>
        </div> 

        <ul id="actionList"></ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer" class="footer">
    <ul id="azioni">
    </ul>       
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/iscroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/xlist.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: what have you tried ? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: This is the correct code. I can't understand how to handle wrapper and wrapper_hidden!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with one of the examples first. Jquery mobile changes the way your application is structured. You're not including `jquery-mobile.js`, so your example does not work.

The  should be around your header, data and footer, but in order to have multiple (inline) pages, you need more of them.